# Need specific part of a column as other column value

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I need to use **1005187069_0_A233-107400-1.pdf** from below string as a part of my other column values in ssis derived column transformation which is connected to Flat file source.

`\\Hprweb001\ftp_root\HRPFTP\Usr\MediConnect\InboundImages\1005187069_0_A233-107400-1.pdf`

I know it is possible with the help of substring function and I tried:

```
SUBSTRING( [Column 5] , 1, FINDSTRING( [Column 5] , " ",1 )-FINDSTRING( [Column 5] , "\",8 )+1)
```

But it is giving me an error. Please help.

Comment: Which error? Please provide it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the query you need:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @text = '\Hprweb001\ftp_root\HRPFTP\Usr\MediConnect\InboundImages\1005187069_0_A233-107400-1.pdf'

SELECT
  REVERSE(
     SUBSTRING(
        REVERSE(@text),
        0,
        CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@text))
      )
)
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24001) so you can see how it works

Also, another simpler version is:

```
SELECT RIGHT(@text, CHARINDEX('\' ,REVERSE(@text))-1)
```

You can use [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/24003) to run this, and see the result.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and solution. However, I want to use this expression in derived column transformation in ssis. I modified it but still no success. Any help is greatly appreciated.        RIGHT( Column 5 ,FINDSTRING("\",REVERSE(Column 5 ))-1)

Comment: @user2933406 And what is the issue? Do you have an error? If so, you can post a comment with it.

Comment: It Doesn't Parse.                                                 TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [553]]: Parsing the expression "REVERSE( SUBSTRING( REVERSE( [Column 5] ) , 0, FINDSTRING( '\', REVERSE, [Column 5]  )  )  )" failed. The single quotation mark at line number "1", character number "60", was not expected.

Comment: @ChelChabiloGujrati In FINDSTRING function, you have a comma after `REVERSE` instead of a paranthesis.